# Dynamics AX 2012 SRSS report: SysDictClass object not initialised

Tags: report, axapta, ax, dynamics-ax-2012

I created a report Data Provider class that returns a temp table and a Data Contract for the parameters (as per http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg731917.aspx). I created a report in Visual Studio. When I test the report in VS, it works perfectly, I get data etc. However, when I run the report in AX, the dialog requesting the parameters is displayed - but the report keeps on giving me a `SysDictClass object not initialised` error in the infolog.

The stack trace I get is:

```
Stack trace

(S)\Classes\SRSReportProviderMetadata\getDataContract - line 14
(S)\Classes\SRSReportProviderMetadata\initParameters - line 7
(S)\Classes\SRSReportProviderMetadata\new - line 20
(S)\Classes\SRSReportProviderMetadata\constructWithId - line 16
(S)\Classes\SRSReportProviderMetadata\constructWithName - line 16
(S)\Classes\SrsReportProviderQueryBuilder\initialize - line 10
(S)\Jobs\
```

Any ideas why this might occur?

Answer (score 2):

This indicates that the `SRSReportParameterAttribute.getContractId` method does not return a valid class id. That is a mystery as the returned value is validated in its `new` method.

Try to redeploy your report, right click your SSRS report in AX, then select "Deploy".

If that does not work try a full recompile of the application.

Comment: I'm having this ServiceGroups, is there a solution?

Comment: What ServiceGroups, try again?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Properties of `Data Contract` class and make sure that `RunOn` property is set to `Called from`.